# Herkunft von "von ungefähr kommen"?

Tags: meaning, etymology, phrase

Beispiel: "Hochwertige Technik und innovative Produkte kommen nicht von ungefähr."

Woher stammt die Phrase "(nicht) von ungefähr kommen"?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Etymologisch hatte *ungefähr*, früher *[ohngefehr](http://woerterbuchnetz.de/DWB/?sigle=DWB&mode=Vernetzung&lemid=GO01090)*, die Bedeutung *ohne böse Absicht, ohne Hinterlist*, die sich danach zu *absichtslos*, *ohne jegliche Absicht*, also, *zufällig* entwickelte. Auch nachzulesen im [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=ungef%C3%A4hr).

Die ursprüngliche Bedeutung findet sich noch im Substantiv *Ungefähr* ([veraltend](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Ungefaehr)), das *Zufall, Schicksal* bedeutet. Von der alten Bedeutung des Worts ist aber nur die Wendung *nicht von ungefähr kommen* geblieben.

*Nicht kommen von* heißt *keine Folge von etwas sein*.

Der vollständige Satz bedeutet also

> Hochwertige Technik und innovative Produkte stehen uns zur Verfügung nicht durch Zufall.

Mit ein bisschen mehr Freiheit:

> Man hat hochwertige Technik und innovative Produkte aus gutem Grund.

oder

> Die Existenz hochwertiger Technik und innovativer Produkte ist gut begründet.