# Does "paar" still mean "two items"? Words that have lost their original meaning

Tags: idiom, history, evolution

> –Ich hätte gerne ein Paar Brötchen
>   –Wie viele?

That was (modulo trivialities) a conversation that surprised me. Of course –assuming the grammatical correctness of the sentences–, the baker doesn't see that I was meaning *Paar* and not *paar*, but I'm bemused by the fact that, in absence of more data, he didn't think that I was actually asking for *precisely two items*.

It is therefore credible, referring to [this question](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1197/wie-viele-sind-ein-paar), that not only *paar* means rather "a few", but that in the native speaker’s mind the distance between this word and "two items" is huge.

**Questions:**

- Is this related to a orthography reform? Perhaps *Paar→paar* (I guess [no](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=paar%2F%28paar%2BPaar%29&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=20&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%28paar%20/%20%28paar%20%2B%20Paar%29%29%3B%2Cc0)).   If not, why/when did  this change take place? (in case the phenomenon has been studied)
- Could somebody warn non-native speakers from using certain words or expressions, which have lost its original meaning as well? I ask in the sense of this answer [Ungefähr→ungefähr](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/7441/herkunft-von-von-ungefahr-kommen).

  ---

**Edit**: My argument behind the first question has been refuted in the answers bellow. I thought *paar* came from *Paar*, which I thought meant originally *exactly two* items. It comes from the Latin *par (paris)*, which mean two equal. 
The argument *only motivates* the second question, which therefore remains **valid**.

Comment: Ein [Paar](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Paar) Schuhe, aber [ein paar](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/ein_paar) Brötchen. - Ein Paar beschreibt immer zwei zusammengehörige Dinge. Brötchen gehören aber nicht zusammen. Deswegen wird der Bäcker immer von *ein paar* Brötchen ausgehen.

Comment: Also note that [apparently](http://xkcd.com/1070/) in English not everyone thinks that “a couple of” has to refer to exactly two, either.

Comment: @CarstenSchultz: Yes; this seems to be a dialectical difference in English.  In some places/age groups, *a couple of X’s* unambiguously means two X’s.  In other places, the meaning has shifted/generalised from this, to mean roughly “a few”/“several”, although in some contexts (e.g. “Jack and Jill are a couple”) it means exactly-two-with-some-specific-relationship.  It seems very plausible that *Paar*/*paar* is exactly the same divergence, but taken further — can anyone with German etymology reference confirm/deny this?

Comment: One of the local bakers has begun selling ‘Zwillingssemmeln’. When I naively asked for ‘eine Semmel’, the person behind the counter asked back ‘eine Einzelne oder ein Paar?’ I guess in such a case ‘ein Paar Semmeln’ will net you two rolls, no questions asked.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The word *Paar* doesn't only mean *two items* but rather *two items that are related to one another*. The prime example is

> Mike und Jenny sind ein Paar.

This notion also shows in compounds like *Paartherapie*, *Paartanz* or *paarweise.* 
The situation of using *Paar* as a qualifying noun is rather rare. The only example I can think of is this:

> Ein Paar Schuhe.

This makes sense because the shoes are related to one another. Most Germans would understand this as a pair.

*Ein Paar Brötchen.* on the other hand doesn't make sense. How can buns be related? So a listener will autmatically assume that you meant *paar*. Hence the question. 
It has nothing to do with spelling reform or anything. The sentence:

> Ich möchte ein Paar Brötchen.

does not make sense in writing either. The point is that 2 buns lack the relationship that is necessary for a *Paar*.

Comment: "Ein Paar Brötchen" may very well make sense and the expression "ein Paar XY" is quite common for certain food-items. Both buns and e.g. sausages are often actually sold in pairs like http://www.meckback.de/index.php?strg=19_22&baseID=22&dataID=22 or http://www.fleischerei-goebser.de/shop/product_info.php?products_id=79 .

Comment: @jarnbjo... you're totally right with the "Paar Wiener". That I do know. As for the buns... well, they use marketing language but the item itself is not referred to as "ein Paar Brötchen". Anyway, there might be more examples, but I think "quite common" is a bit of an exaggeration ;)

Comment: As a fun fact: Not everything that ends with *paar* could be decoupled. "*ein Schuhpaar*" is the same as "*ein Paar Schuhe*" whereas "*ein Brautpaar*" is not the same as "*ein paar Bräute*", which would mean "*some hot chicks*". :)

Comment: +1 But actually, there is the "Paarweck" which even has the "Paar" in it's name: https://holzbackofen.rainer-grundel.de/rezept/paarweck-wasserweck/
But this is more of a regional exception.

Comment: My English teacher tried to convince me that in German, "ein Paar Jeans" refers to one single clothing item for your legs, whereas everybody I knew would say "eine Jeans" (and understand his example as "ein paar Jeans" = "einige Jeans"). Nevertheless, this anecdote at least  irrevocably burnt the corresponding English examples into my brain: "a pair of trousers" = "eine Hose", "a pair of scissors" = "eine Schere"

Answer (score 7):

While Emanuel's answer is right, it is lengthy. Simply put

> Ein Paar > a pair of
>   Ein paar > a couple/few

You then have to figure out the subtle differences, like for example

> Heute habe ich ein Paar Jeans gekauft
>   Heute habe ich ein paar Jeans gekauft

(Solution: *Ein Paar Jeans* = *a pair of jeans* = one piece, *ein paar Jeans* = more than one piece)

Comment: Note that *a couple of* can mean *a few* as in "a couple of minutes". So, from that standpoint, *couple* is the English 'counterpart' to *paar/Paar*.

Comment: Changed my answer to reflect the fact that even though I use *a couple of* in the sense of *exactly two*, common understanding seems to be that it rather means *a few*.

Comment: "a pair of trees" ... this would not be translated using Paar. https://www.google.de/search?q=%22a+pair+of%22&rlz=1C1DVCJ_enDE430DE443&oq=%22a+pair+of%22&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.5561j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=%22a+pair+of+trees%22

The reason: Paar used as an adjective is rather rare in German and almost only applies to shoes. I even find it odd with Jeans because I buy "eine Jeans". Thus your answer is misleading. Same for "a pair of forks" or "a pair of toothpicks"

Comment: To put more direct: `ein Paar Jeans` bedeutet ganz klar zwei Jeans. Jeans, Hose und ähnliche Bekleidungsstücke sind im Deutschen ganz klar Singular.

Comment: @Toscho: mir ist der Gebrauch von _ein Paar Jeans/Hosen_ im Sinne von _eine Jeans/Hose_ durchaus geläufig, vor allem in der Generation, die um die Mitte des 20. Jhdts geboren wurde.

Comment: @Toscho: Mir wiederum sind Begriffe wie *ein Paar Hosen* oder *ein Paar Socken* durchaus geläufig. Und besonders bei den Socken wirst Du mir dann wohl zustimmen müssen, dass *ein Paar Socken* und *ein paar Socken* nicht zwangsläufig das gleiche sind.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Socken sind auch keine den Jeans oder Hosen ähnliche Bekleidungsstücke: Sie hängen nicht zusammen. Ein Paar Socken besteht aus zwei Körpern, die ohne Probleme räumlich getrennt werden können. Bei Hosen, Jeans und ähnlichem ist das nicht der Fall.

Comment: @Toscho Klar kann man sagen *ich kaufe mir eine Jeans*. Man kann aber auch sagen *Ich kaufe mir ein Paar Jeans* oder *Ich kaufe mir ein Paar Hosen*. Und beides meint nur einen Gegenstand. Das ist historisch gesehen die gleiche Form wie das englische *pair of Jeans*. Das kannst Du jetzt einsehen oder nicht, aber trotzdem gibt es den Ausdruck :-)

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar Den historischen Zusammenhang sehe ich völlig ein, aber in der aktuellen, deutschen Umgangssprache bedeutet `ein Paar Jeans` eben zwei Jeans.

Comment: @Toscho Google mal nach "ein Paar Jeans". Wie erklärst Du mir dann so Sachen wie "mit 5 Paar Jeans quer durch London" oder "2 Paar Jeans für nur X Euro"? In der aktuellen deutschen Umgangssprache bedeutet "ein Paar Jeans" eben nach wie vor "eine Hose" und "ein paar Jeans" eben "mehrere Hosen". Nur dass man die Groß- und Kleinschreibung eben nicht hört.

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Unter "5 Paar Jeans" bzw. "2 Paar Jeans" würde ich als Muttersprachler zunächst mal 10 bzw. 4 Hosen verstehen. Man könnte mutmaßen, dass immer zwei Teile dieselbe Farbe haben, sodass sich mehrere Paare gleichartiger Hosen ergeben.

Answer (score 1):

Lacking the distinction between lower and upper case spelling in a spoken conversation, I guess most people would instead indicate the difference using emphasis:

- Ich hätte gern *ein* Paar Socken.
- Ich hätte gern ein paar *Socken*.

If you emphasize the number, by melody and also by introducing a short pause after it, you stress the fact that you are speaking of a spcific amount. If you don't do that, but instead speak „ein paar“ as a connected phrase without pause or special emphasis, perhaps even colloquially abbreviated to „'n paar“, then it will more likely be interpreted as an imprecise amount.

That said, other answers are correct in stating that Paar usually refers to items with some connection between them that makes them form a unit in some sense. So even if you did use the emphasis as indicated above, the baker might still ask for the precise amount. Which is the reason why I changed my example to something where both meanings are plausible.